# Codeigniter Dynamic select box

Tags: ajax, codeigniter

I am using codeigniter to do a project, Now i am trying to built a dynamic select boxes,but aint working,I am new with AJAX,Please help me

tell me where is error

Comment: Where is you code ? What you have tried yet ?

Comment: AJAX CODE

<script src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/js/jQuery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#course').on('change',function(){
var courseval = $("#course").val()
$.ajax({
type:'POST',
url:"<?php echo base_url(); ?>student/getBranch"+courseval,
success:function(br){
$.each(br,function(branch_name) 
{
var opt = $('<option />'); 
opt.val(branch_name);
opt.text(branch_name);
$('#branch').append(opt); 
});
}
});
});
});
</script>

Comment: HTML CODE

<form action="<?php echo base_url(); ?>student/getBranch" method="post" name="form">
<select id="course" name="course">
<option value="0">Select Course</option>
<?php
if(!empty($dispcourse))
{ 
foreach($dispcourse as $r2)
{
?>
<option value="<?php echo $r2->course_name ?>"><?php $r2->course_name ?></option>
<?php
}
}
?>
</select>
<select  id="branch" name="branch">
<option value="0">Select Branch</option>
<option value="1">Select All</option>
</select>
</form>

Comment: CONTROLLER FUNCTIONS

public function getBranch($courseval)
{
$where = $courseval;
$this->load->model('student_model');
$data['course'] = $this->student_model->branchListing($where);
$br=json_encode($data['course']);
echo $br;
}

Comment: MODEL CLASS

public function branchListing($where)
{
$this->db->select('Basetb.branch_name');
$this->db->from('tbl_branch as Basetb');
$this->db->where('tbl_branch.course',$where);  
$query = $this->db->get();
$result = $query->result();
return $result;
}

public function courseListing()
{
$this->db->select('Basetb.course_name');
$this->db->from('tbl_courses as Basetb');
$query = $this->db->get();
$result = $query->result();        
return $result;
}

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask